# Extract file name from html string using regex in Idoc Script

Tags: regex, idocscript

I need to extract file name of an image from one html string using Idoc Script regex functions.

Input string:

```
"<img src="/cs/content./file_name.png" alt="" />"
```

Output need to be:

```
"file_name"
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. The first capturing group should contain the result:

```
<img\s+src\s*=\s*"[^"]*\/([^"]*)\.[^"]*"[^\/]*\/>
```